# SmartyStreets Jquery thingie not binding to address fields in a modal?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, smartystreets

situation is not limited to SmartyStreet's [Website Plugin](https://smartystreets.com/docs/plugins/website), but its the latest symptom:

A page opens a modal with the following form:

`<form id="frmCreateDonorPerson" action="/donor/createPerson" method="post">
   <input type="text" id="txtLine1" name="txtLine1">
   etc.
   etc.
</form>`

And the following javascript, which *without* the modal situation (i.e. when I navigate straight to the page), had no issue creating a SmartyStreets address validator Jquery experience:

`var ss = jQuery.LiveAddress({
    key: "30340983409834098",
    target: "US",
    addresses: [{
            address1: '#txtLine1',
            etc.
            etc.
    }]
});`

I'm expecting real-time options to be populated by SmartyStreet's website plug while anything is being entered into the "Line1" box.

But...nada.

I've noticed symptoms of this weirdness in other similar situations ("Jquery in a modal"), and I've researched solutions to that problem phrase, but no solutions seem to answer this one..

Thx super much in advance!!!

Comment: In the plugin documentation there are two examples, one is bad modal usage (https://jsfiddle.net/smartystreets/rybo6zqf/) and the other is good modal usage (https://jsfiddle.net/smartystreets/mnh18fx1/). Give those examples a try.

Answer (score 0):

I think by default SmartyStreets object attaches itself to the address field and finds the parent form element within that page.  Does your modal use an iframe or is it inline?  If its an iframe, I think it will have trouble locating the form.